# Spring returns gibberish to JS client

Tags: json, spring

Here is the response I get from my WebSocket controller whenever it publishes a message to it's subscribers

```
n {command: "MESSAGE", headers: {…}, body: "{\"headers\":{},\"body\":{\"sender\":\"b\",\"recipient\":\"my…dy\":\"a\"},\"statusCode\":\"OK\",\"statusCodeValue\":200}", escapeHeaderValues: true, ack: ƒ, …}
ack: ƒ (e)
body: "{\"headers\":{},\"body\":{\"sender\":\"b\",\"recipient\":\"myself\",\"body\":\"a\"},\"statusCode\":\"OK\",\"statusCodeValue\":200}"
command: "MESSAGE"
escapeHeaderValues: true
headers: {content-length: "108", message-id: "ec3f952a-e9f6-2d4e-997b-07bd18bd5d58-14", subscription: "sub-0", content-type: "application/json", destination: "/topic/greetings"}
```

Everything gets garbled into one ugly string under "body", even though when I log the messages in my server, I see a proper JSON object.

Here is my controller

```
public class WebsocketController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketController.class) ;

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public ResponseEntity<MyMessage> webSocketMessage(MyMessage message) {
        LOGGER.info("Msg is : " + message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
  }
```

And my JS client

```
        function connect() {
            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081/gs-guide-websocket');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', (messageOutput) => {
                    console.log(messageOutput);
                    showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
                });
               
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, but still don't understand some parts:

My response is already a JSON. However, the body is a string NOT in JSON form, so I wrote this to fix it:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body).body);
```

It's a solution, but it smells. If someone could shed some light on why the body of the response came as a string and not as a JSON it would be great.